# How do you keep track of the process of an UX project?

Tags: design-process, user-centered-design, planning

I'm **NOT** looking for an explanation about User Experience itself. But how to keep track of the (development) process of an UX project. Like how do you plan, manage, measure the UX of an project?

Comment: I'm afraid product / book recommendations aren't in scope for this stack exchange site. We're here to solve specific UX issues, not to recommend products that will likely be out of date within a few months.

Comment: Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get more thorough than Designing For the Digital Age by Kim Goodwin. It covers – in incredible detail for all conceivable situations – a project from inception to production. Explains how to build a team, how to properly research, how to build personas, and so on. It's a heavy read, but there's something in it for everyone. Highly recommended.

[http://www.amazon.com/Designing-Digital-Age-Human-Centered-Products/dp/0470229101/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470229101)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Lean UX by Jeff Gothelf?

There is a Lean UX conference coming to NYC in April: 
http://2015.leanuxnyc.co/

Comment: That was the first book I had in mind, but I prefer a more general UX planning/project book.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. It's called the Project Guide to UXD:

http://www.amazon.ca/Project-Guide-Design-experience-designers/dp/0321607376

Comment: I think that this book explains the very basics of UX. But I need a more detailed book that gives me the knowledge to map an clear UX project/process.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this book as an UX project/process Guide? Has anyone read this? [http://www.amazon.com/The-UX-Book-Guidelines-Experience/dp/0123852412](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123852412)